# why are all the weights of the Gaussian quadrature formula non zero

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let us assume that we want integrate $f(x)$ in the interval $[-1,1]$ and
obtain the approximation (Gauss quadrature)

\begin{eqnarray}
   \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx \approx \sum_{i=0}^n w_i f(x_i)
\end{eqnarray}
where $x_i$ are the solutions the solutions of the equation $P_n(x)=0$
where $P_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Legendre polinomial and the weights
$w_i$ can be obtained from Lagrange interpolation from the formula
\begin{eqnarray}
   w_i = \int_{-1}^1 \prod_{i=0, i \ne j}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j} dx.
\end{eqnarray}

Is there a simple way to show that $w_i \ne 0$, $i=0,1, \cdots, n$?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Proof_that_the_weights_are_positive

Answer (score 1):

There are other formulas for finding the weights.

For example  $$w_i = \frac {-2}{(n+1)P'_n(x_i)P_{n+1}(x_i)} $$
 Which clearly shows $$ w_i\ne 0 $$

For derivation of this formula  see Atkinson,$1989, p.276$;Ralston and Rabinowitz,$1978, p. 105.$

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I was looking for something simpler....

Comment: For the first few weights, we can use consistency requirement to find the actual values, but in general we need a formula to work with.

Comment: I am in the process of doing this using a Vandermonde system, for which there is an explicit and positive set of weights.

Comment: The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature has some interesting formulas. $w_i=2/(1-x_i^2)[ P_n'(x_i)]^2$ among others.....

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed this proof from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature).

Consider
\begin{eqnarray}
  f(x) = \prod_{j=0, j \ne i}^n  \frac{(x - x_j)^2}{(x_i-x_j)^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Then $f(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$ and $f$ is a polynomial.

To compute this formula we use Gauss quadrature. Since the order
of $f$ is $2n$, it is smaller than $2n+2$ so
the Gauss quadrature is exact (0 error). Then the evaluation of $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)$ is

\begin{eqnarray}
  \int_{-1}^1 f(x) dx = \sum_{j=0}^n w_j f(x_j) = \sum_{j=0}^n \delta_{ij} w_j = w_i > 0.
\end{eqnarray}